# GridsearchCV for the preproessing of ML model based on accuracy

Tags: optimization, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I want to find 2 optimal values for a preprocessing of an ML model.
The 2 (Integers) values will be used to remove some of the input data.

The optimizations will be based on the ML model accuracy.
How can I use gridsearchCV to optimize the preprocessing value?

I created a function of the whole model and now only the hyperparameters of this function need to be optimized based on the model accuracy

Below is the function I created

```py
def The_Function(pTH=0.02, pL=100 ):
    import numpy as np

    
    #initial values
    read_data = []
    label_data = []
    #Ues the function to get features and labels of the data
    #DS\Emirate- dataset\Train
    #DS\SAVEE , DS\EMODB
    read_data, label_data = data_collection("DS/savee", iTH = pTH, iL = pL)
    read_data = shuffle(read_data)
    read_data = shuffle(read_data)
    
    
    # #--------------------------------------------------------------------Read csv from a file
    #Convert to DF
    Dataset = read_data
    Dataset = pd.DataFrame(Dataset)
    
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------Normlise the Features
    X = Dataset.loc[:,0:(Dataset.shape[1] - 2)].copy()

    #X_norm = ( X - X.min() ) / ( X.max() - X.min()) * 10
    X_norm = ( X - X.min() ) / ( X.max() - X.min())
    #X_norm =(X-X.min())/(X.max()-X.min())
    #X_norm = X_norm.fillna(0)

    for i in range(X_norm.shape[1]):
        if  math.isnan(X_norm[i].mean()) :
            #print(X_norm[i])
            #print(X_norm[i].mean())
            X_norm[i] = X_norm[i].fillna(0)
            #print(X_norm[i])
        else:
            pass
            #X_norm[i] = X_norm[i].fillna(X_norm[i].mean())

    X_norm.describe()
    

    
    c = Dataset.shape[1]
    Y = Dataset.loc[:,[c-1]]
    Y = Y.astype(int)
    Y[:2]

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------Updated Dataset 
    Dataset2 = X_norm
    c = Dataset.shape[1]
    Y = Dataset.loc[:,[c-1]].copy()
    Y = Y.astype(int)
    Dataset2["Y"] = Y.copy()
    Dataset2.describe()
    Dataset2[:2]
    
    X = Dataset2.loc[:,:Dataset2.shape[1]-2].copy()

    Y = np.array(Y)
    X = np.array(X)

    Y[:3]
    
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------XY Split:
    Y = Dataset2.loc[:,"Y"].copy()
    Y = Y.astype(int)
    X = Dataset2.loc[:,0:(Dataset2.shape[1] - 2)].copy()

    #X = X[selected_mrmr[:500]]

    nft = X.shape[1]
    print(X.shape)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------KFold Split:
    X = np.array(X)
    Y = np.array(Y)
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    kf = KFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True, random_state = 23123)
    kf.get_n_splits(X)
    print(kf)

    spt = 0
    svm_accuracy = np.array([])


    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
        spt+=1

        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        Y_train, Y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]

        nft = X_train.shape[1]
        #SVM
        #from sklearn.svm import SVC,SVR,LinearSVC,LinearSVR
        from sklearn.svm import SVC
        from sklearn import svm
        from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

        #clf_svm = svm.SVR( kernel = 'poly' )
        clf_svm = SVC( kernel = 'poly' , decision_function_shape='ovo')
        #clf_svm = svm.SVR(kernel='poly')

        clf_svm.fit(X_train, Y_train)
        print("\n\n###################################################################################")
        print("Split =",spt)
        print("SVM Train accuracy ",nft,":",accuracy_score(Y_train, clf_svm.predict(X_train)))
        print("SVM Test accuracy ",nft,':',accuracy_score(Y_test, clf_svm.predict(X_test)))
        print(clf_svm.predict(X_test)[:5])
        svm_accuracy = np.append(svm_accuracy, accuracy_score(Y_test, clf_svm.predict(X_test)))
        print(svm_accuracy)

        #################################
        print(X.shape[1])
        print("SVM:",svm_accuracy.mean())
    return(svm_accuracy.mean())
```

I need to optimize the 2 values of the preprocessing of the model based on the model accuracy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **optimize** some **preprocessing parameters**, the easiest way is to put the preprocessing part and your model in a [Scikit-Learn pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html). You can then optimize your preprocessing parameters with a [grid search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). In the Scikit-Learn documentation, you have an example of the optimisation of the number of PCA components in the preprocessing part of the pipeline : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html

Comment: Thank you for the help.

I hope this work note (the data will be changed -> extract the feature -> feature selection -> test the model performance -> repeat until optimized)